# Firefox shows gray rectangle on drag&drop

Tags: firefox, arch-linux

For some weeks now Firefox shows a gray rectangle when I move mails using drag & drop in Outlook Web Access:

[image: The gray area is what I mean. Yes, this big gray area.]

Does anyone have a similar issue? Does anyone have an idea where this comes from? The drag & drop still works, but it's hard to determine, which folder you are dropping the mail.

Some details about my machine:

- Operating System: Archlinux (up to date)
- Desktop: Mate 1.16.1
- Firefox: 50.1.0

Comment: Btw: I already tried to fix it by deleting the firefox configuration folder and start firefox again with a fresh profile. Does not work.

Comment: I assume you have no extensions, other than one from Archlinux? You might try disabling it, if there is one (I know Ubuntu has one add-on, but I don't know about Arch).

Comment: No. No single add-on. Only one plugin: `OpenH264 Video Codec provided by Cisco System...` which is disabled.